# Matching between $n$ men and $m$ women

Tags: graph-theory, network-flow, matroids

There is a group of $n$ men and $m$ women, and there is a symmetric dating between them (between the men and the women).

How can we find a match between the men and the women (depending to the dating) that will be a **maximum** match (by the size), but the sum of the ages of the women is **minimal**!

If there such a way for this I'd like to get proof for it because I try to find one with a proof and I can't :-(

Hall's theorem helps here or not?
But it something close, right?

I think about a variant of Belman-Ford algorithem?
(Maybe there in no perfect matching, but I'm wonder if B-F algorithm can find maximum matching).

Thank you so much!

P.S. I don't how to say at English, but when I'm write **maximum** match I mean for the match with the maximum **SIZE** (you cant add more..)... (hope this is the right term).

Comment: A dating means a symmetric relation? By a match you mean a subset of that relation such that each man/woman is related to at most one woman/man? Whatever you ask, it must be possible as it is a finite problem. So, are you looking for some complexity bounds fo an algorithm? The question is unclear as it stands.

Comment: @PeterFranek - Thank you for you comment, I'll try to make it clear:  
A dating means a symmetric relation?  **Yes** (I, wrote it, no?).   
By a match you mean a subset of that relation such that each man/woman is related to at most one woman/man? **Yes** (I don't understand the meaning of: ___at most one woman/man___ but I think you right...).
**Yes** - It's finite problem...  
So, are you looking for some complexity bounds for an algorithm? **Yes**...
I hope now it's more clear...

Comment: @hardmath - Thank you! I fix it!! :-) Hope now it's more clear...

Comment: What you describe is a problem of finding a minimum weighted matching of maximum cardinality in a bipartite graph.  This problem is considered by Valencia and Vargas in this 2014 arXiv publication, [Optimum matchings in weighted bipartite graphs](http://arxiv.org/abs/1403.5606), where your weights are the ages of the women.

Comment: Do you have a it shorter? i.e. a summery of it?

Comment: Your weights are of a special form, namely depending only on the "right-hand" endpoint (the age of the woman), so it is possible that algorithms can take advantage of this circumstance.  Are you looking for an algorithm to implement, or simply for complexity results?

Comment: @hardmath - yes I'm looking for an algorithm to implement... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me sketch an approach to solving this problem which replaces the *minimum* weight requirement with a *maximum* weight objective.

It requires finding at least one *maximum* matching in the bipartite graph $G \subseteq \{m_1,\ldots,m_n\} \times \{w_1,\ldots,w_m\}$ of "men" and "women".

If $G$ were the complete bipartite graph $K_{n,m}$ this would be trivial, as the maximum size of a matching is the minimum of $n$ and $m$, and knowing the size allows any subset of the larger "part" to be used for a perfect matching on that subgraph.

Let $V=n+m$ be the number of vertices and $E$ the number of edges in $G$.  A well-known approach such as [Ford-Fulkerson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford%E2%80%93Fulkerson_algorithm) (1956) can find a maximum matching in $G$ in polynomial time, $O(VE)$.  According to Alom, Das, and Islam (2010), [Finding the Maximum Matching in a Bipartite Graph](http://www.duet.ac.bd/journal/5.pdf), this can be improved to "almost $O(E)$" (see Sec. 5).  If true, this would be a very interesting result.  However the algorithm of [Hopcroft and Karp](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.186.3904&rep=rep1&type=pdf) only requires $O(V^{1/2} E)$ steps in any case.

However your problem goes beyond asking for a maximum matching to one of these that minimizes the total ages of women in the matching.  For this we could enumerate all possible maximum matchings and pick the one with the least total ages.  See the Section below on methods for doing this, but the number of possible maximum matchings can grow exponentially.

Fortunately we can transform our requirement of minimizing the edge weights in a maximum matching *in this specific problem* to a requirement of maximizing the sum of edge weights.  Intuitively let $M$ be a very large number, and replace the weight of the edge from $m_i$ to $w_j$ by $M-a_j$, where $a_j$ is the age of the woman $w_j$, the original weight of that edge.

Now maximizing the sum of the new edge weights in a matching will tend to maximize the size of the matching, because $M$ is very large.  At the same time, among matchings of that maximum size, clearly the one with the largest sum of edge weights is the one for which the sum of corresponding $a_j$ is least.

To be rigorous about this, let $M \gt \sum_{j=1}^m a_j$.  Suppose $k$ is the size of a maximum matching on $G$.  Then for any matching of size less than $k$, the sum of edge weights is at most $(k-1)M$.  For any matching of size $k$, the sum of edge weights is at least $kM - \sum_{j=1}^m a_j$.  By our choice of $M$:

$$ (k-1)M \lt kM - \sum_{j=1}^m a_j$$

Therefore the maximum weight matching on $G$ with transformed weights is a maximum bipartite matching which minimizes the sum of ages $a_j$ appearing in the match.

Now a maximum weight bipartite matching can be found by a "greedy algorithm" that exploits the matroid structure of these problems.

**Notes on enumerating all maximum matchings**

The literature on enumerating all maximum matchings is fairly mature.  T. Uno (1997) proposed [Algorithms for Enumerating All Perfect, Maximum and
Maximal Matchings in Bipartite Graphs](http://research.nii.ac.jp/~uno/papers/isaac97web.pdf) that begin by finding one maximum matching in $O(V^{1/2} E)$ time, using the ideas that go back to [Hopcroft and Karp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopcroft%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm) (1973).  After this "pre-processing" phase the algorithm finds additional maximum matchings at a cost of $O(V)$ per maximum matching.

The paper [Finding All Allowed Edges in a Bipartite Graph](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1107.4711.pdf) by Tamir Tassa (2011) seems to give a good survey of the known literature on finding maximum matchings.  The application there is to finding all the edges of a bipartite graph which belong to *some* maximum matching, once a single maximum matching is known, in $O(V+E)$ time.  The Introduction of this paper describes a matchmaking agency with a setup very similar to what is described in this Question.

Comment: I think it's belong to Matroids, right?

Comment: @Yoar: No, I suspect not.  When the matroid structure is available in a problem, there is generally a successful "greedy algorithm" to solve it.  I don't see that here, but perhaps I'm over-complicating your problem.

Comment: @Yoar: My suspicions are beginning to turn toward your idea that there is a matroid structure here.  First, finding a maximum matching is an example of this (see this [previous Question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/234811/show-that-a-matched-set-of-nodes-forms-a-matroid?rq=1) and its Answer).  The second thing we need to deal with is the optimization of weighted edges (ages), and I think there's a trick to make this into a maximum flow problem.

Comment: @Yoar: I edited my answer to reflect the transformation of the problem to give a matroid structure.